# how do functional languages handle manipulating array arguments if arguments are non mutable?

Tags: functional-programming

I am reading about functional languages and I can't understand this particular thing. Suppose a function takes an array of numbers and has to square each number. What if we need to remove or insert some elements? Do we have to return a copy of the mutated array for every operation? If so how are arrays of hundreds of millions of objects manipulated reasonably?

Comment: An array is not functional. You cannot study FP using imperative data structures, because as you have already noticed this doesn't make sense. Take a look at Clojure's Vectors to get an intuition.

Comment: "Do we have to return a copy of the mutated array for every operation" - depends on the language (some: yes, some: no, some can actually do mutation for real). "how are arrays of hundreds of millions of objects manipulated reasonably" - sharing. Suppose you have an array with 1000 elements and you change the element at index 123. You might think you now have 2000 elements. In fact, you can get away with 1001 elements, with the other 999 shared between the two "arrays".

Comment: While some functional programming languages (OCaml being a notable example) do have imperative features like arrays with mutable state for pragmatic reasons, if you are trying to learn how to think like a functional programmer, and you're using the word "arrays" you're probably on the wrong track. :)

Comment: But also, most functional programming languages use garbage collection. So if I have data structure A, and apply function F to it, getting data structure B back, if I never use A again, that memory is freed up and I don't worry about it. As you try to learn how to think like a functional programmer, don't try to _convert_ code you've written in C or Java or Python. Think about the core problem. Go back to basics. And build a functional solution from there.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways that functional languages handle array arguments.

1. Don't actually use arrays.

Instead of using arrays, one should almost always use some other data structure. Lists, binary search trees, finger trees, functional queues, and other data structures are commonly employed in functional code instead of arrays. It often takes some thought to pick the best data structure.

2. Have a "special escape hatch" for using mutation.

In Haskell, there is a magical thing known as the `ST` monad. This allows you to write code in Haskell which manipulates mutable arrays in an imperative style while still guaranteeing that the mutation can't "leak out" the escape hatch. For example, if I have a function `f :: Int -> Int` and I call `f 3` twice, I am guaranteed to get the same results each time even if the function internally uses a mutable array. This is not the case in a language like Java, since calling `f(3)` might read from and write to mutable state, but in Haskell, you can use mutation fairly freely without compromising purity using `ST`.

3. Use linear types.

This is a relatively recent addition to Haskell. Consider a function `modify :: Int -> a -> Array a -> Array a`, where `modify idx new_val original_array` should return a new array which is a copy of `original_array`, except that position `idx` has been overwritten with value `new_val`. If we never read from the array `original_array` after we call the `modify` function on it, then it's ok for the compiler to secretly modify `original_array` rather than creating a new array without breaking the abstraction of the code. Linear types basically enforce this restriction within the language. It's rather sophisticated and takes some getting used to, but it allows you to use an underlying mutable data structure safely with functional abstractions. It's more limited than `ST` but doesn't involve any "imperative thinking".

4. Use immutable arrays.

You might just bite the bullet and use arrays that must be copied on modification. This is very rarely optimal, but the language may offer some abstractions that make this less bearable and more asymptotically efficient in certain circumstances.

Comment: Linear types have an exactly-use-once semantics. If you relax this property to use-at-most-once than you have Rust's affine types, AFAIK. Affine types can be implemented in Javascript using a function wrapper.

Comment: quite interesting, but which method has the best speed and space preformance?

Comment: @devintern It depends on the context. In many cases, approach 1 is good enough to get optimal asymptotic performance (for example, it's possible to do radix sort using a functional trie instead of an array with the same asymptotic time/space characteristics). But there are some cases where there isn't a known functional data structure that can beat a mutable array (or when the known functional data structure is fiendishly complex - for example, there's a functional double-ended queue with O(1) pops, catenation, and reversal, but it's really nasty to implement) and the other methods are better.